# Irregular behaviour when mixing subfiles and topmargin

Tags: margins, subfiles

I want to use `\topmargin` within my subfile as seen in `coversheet.tex`.

If I compile just `coversheet.tex` this works perfectly. 
But if I compile `main.tex` the topmargin is just ignored. 
Is there a reason for this strange behaviour ?

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %German language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Bilder
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\topmargin = -2.7cm
\subfile{Coversheet.tex}
%\topmargin = -0cm
\subfile{Erklaerung.tex}

\end{document}
```

**coversheet.tex**

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\textwidth 16.7cm
\textheight 25cm
\topmargin -2.7cm
\oddsidemargin 0.25cm
\parindent 0pt
\pagestyle{empty}

This is an example

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the subfile is inside group (environment `document` redefined) so you need to make assignments global

```
\documentclass[b.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\global\textwidth 16.7cm
\global\textheight 25cm
\global\topmargin -2.7cm
\global\oddsidemargin 0.25cm
\global\parindent 0pt
\pagestyle{empty}

This is an example 

\end{document}
```